# Blender Evee volumentrics aren't working as they are supposed to

Tags: eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

why does my cube look so bad while the other one looks so crisp and detailed

[image: bad]

[image: good]

Answer (score 2):

The quality of volumetrics is largely controlled by the Tile Size and the number of Samples:

[image: VolumeQuality]

To better control the definition of the volume, use a ColorRamp.

[image: ColorRampVolume]

Comment: Start and End can make a huge difference to quality also - since the concentrates the sample into a narrower region.